# Export Report format PDF in SpagoBI

Tags: pdf, export, export-to-pdf, spagobi

When i export report in SpagoBI with format PDF,the page is cut in the right.

[Report in SpagoBI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/os8kQ.png)
[Report after export PDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEeGm.png) 
How to resolve this problem?
Thanks

Comment: May be your page layout is set to Fixed Layout change it to Automatic and give it a try.

Comment: @NIket it's a customization in XLM source in tag <page-setup>. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

When you develop report from SpagoBI Studio
change setting of Master Page (next to Layout)
and increase the width of report. 
make sure it is greater than the table(component of report)

This will solve Export as pdf as well as other format issues like excel